# How to reversly fill a silder in javafx

Tags: javafx, slider

Can the fill of a vertical slider be reversed? As you can see in the figure, the slider is filling from 12, but I want it to be from -24. Is there any solution?

```
What's happening     What i want
12.0                   12.0 
 -                      
 -                        
 - - - - - 0 - - - - -  -                          
                        -
                        -
                        -
-24.0                -24.0
```

Update : I'm recently using JMetro css stylesheets for my app.

Comment: Is it slider or progressbar? How are you initiating that control and setting the 12 and -24 values to it?

Comment: 'Slider slider = new Slider(-24.0,12.0,0);'

Comment: Sliders don't "fill". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/slider.htm#CCHFBJCH for some screenshots and usage. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I'm unable to give screenshots nd thus the situation is occuring. From the min value to the present value, the slider's track changes color or something observable visual. Talking about that.

Comment: By the way, I'm using JMetro css stylesheets for my app.

Comment: Hmm. . The author seems to fix it. See https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/metro-style-slider-for-java-update-jmetro/

Comment: Please edit your question with details you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Uluk Biy. But that just has solved one part. And hopefully I've managed to solve the other. Now it's done. :)

Comment: @Subhranil, there was only **one** part in the question ;). Anyway glad to hear that. You may post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after the link provided by @Uluk Biy I've got the refurnished code, which itself needed a refurnishment. The problem was still not solved.The slider had just been set to its proper vertical orientation but the track was still filling from bottom. Just open `FilledSliderSkin.java`, go to line 324, and replace the `fill.resizeRelocate(x,y,width,height)` with the following :

```
fill.resizeRelocate(trackLeft,
thumb.getLayoutY(),
trackWidth,
((int)trackLength + trackStart - trackRadius) - thumb.getLayoutY());
```

Now you're done. :)